# I did understand the original proof given in CLRS, but in the given corollary why does the cut VC,(V-VC) respect A?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

Corollary. Let A be subset of E that is included in some MST for G, let
C = (VC, EC) be a connected component (tree) in forest GA = (V, A).
If (u, v) is a light edge connecting C to some other component in GA,
then (u, v) is safe for A.
Proof. The cut (VC, V − VC) respects A (A defines the components
of GA), and (u, v) is a light edge for this cut. Therefore, (u, v) is safe
for A.

Comment: I suspect this is an excerpt from CLRS.  You should include [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for people to be able to help.

Comment: I'm not clear on all the definitions, but I'm guessing that this is what is happening: if an edge e of A has one vertex in VC and another vertex v in V-VC, then the connected component C would have to include e and hence v. But we are told it does not include v.